# Call R Script from PHP on Linux server

Tags: php, r, linux

I have R installed on my Linux server - typing "R" on the terminal confirms it is installed.

Now, I'm trying to run a simple R Script from PHP.
These are the two files I'm testing - both on the same directory:

`PHP`:

```
<?php
 echo exec("RScript io.R");
?>
```

`io.R`:

```
print("io")
```

Opening the php file on a browser I get an empty page. Also, no error is logged.

### Edit 1

I've replaced `exec()` by `system()`, so PHP file now looks like:

```
<?php
 echo system("RScript io.R");
?>
```

But the result is still a blank page.

### Edit 2

I've replaced `exec()` by `passthru()`, so PHP file now looks like:

```
<?php
 echo passthru("RScript io.R");
?>
```

But the result is still a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `system()` instead of `exec()` if you want the results of the R script to be outputted directly.

See [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) for more details.

Comment: @semaphorims, thanks for your help. I've replaced exec() by system(), but the result is the same a blank page.